# Google API places ID

Tags: java, .net

We are using Google API Places but we check that there is an error while we try to get Place ID from address (es. Viale Regina Margherita, Brindisi, Italia). The same issue is present for other address (es. Pistoia, Italia).
This error can't let us localize correctly the search places on a map.
How we can fix?
Thanks